# Set conditional code based on version of Sklearn library

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

How to set conditional code which only runs when the newer version of Sklearn library is installed, or else skips the code.

I want to check for in Sklearn version 1.2.2 is newer version is installed, if yes, then run the code, otherwise, just skip the functionality.

Im checking sklearn version with

`sklearn.__version__`

I can't check with `int()` or `float()` since 1.2.2 can't be converted into a number, and exact string matching won't account for future releases, like 1.2.3 .

Something like

```
if sklearn.__version__ > 1.2.2 : 
    foo(x)
else:
    bar(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is converting the string into a tuple and comparing the tuples. Tuple comparisons work by comparing the equivalent indexes and moving to the next index if they are equal.

```
version = "1.2.2"
old_version = "1.2.1"
new_version = "1.2.3"

ver_tup = tuple(version.split('.'))
old_ver_tup = tuple(old_version.split('.'))
new_ver_tup = tuple(new_version.split('.'))

print(old_ver_tup > ver_tup)
print(new_ver_tup > ver_tup)

#output 
False
True
```

You can add additional safety by converting the tuple of strings into a tuple of ints, but at least for python 3.10.x that isn't necessary. Since doing `string.split('.')` creates a list, converting it to a tuple also isn't necessary, since both are using the default `Iterable` comparison either way, but I personally prefer keeping my Iterable comparisons to tuples.

Comment: Awesome solution! I was about to give a class-based solution, but this one totally slipped my mind.

Comment: Thanks. But would it account for a situation when version is just 1.0 , and not 1.0.0 ?

Comment: If we do the comparison of `(1,0)` to `(1, 0, 1)`, it would output that `(1,0,1)` is higher. Comparing `(2,0)` to `(1,0,1)` would output that `(2,0)` is higher. The only time this may be problematic is if you compare something like `(1,0)` to `(1,0,0)`, because it will output that `(1,0,0) > (1,0)` is `True`.